# Can't display Viewmodel from EF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, viewmodel

I'm trying to get a agrip on MVC3 but im failing on a Viewmodel which is supposed to display a List but constantly running into an dictionary error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
>   "marc_bew_online.ViewModels.StellenlisteViewModel", but this dictionary requires a model item of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[marc_bew_online.ViewModels.StellenlisteViewModel]".

Here's the code to my repository:

```
public class Stellenbeschr_Repo : IStellenBeschrRepository
{
    marc_bew_entities db = new marc_bew_entities();

    public IEnumerable<STELLENBESCHREIBUNGEN> ListAktuell()
    {

        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
        var stelleBeschreibungAbDatum = (from stellebeschreibung in db.STELLENBESCHREIBUNGEN
                                         where DateTime.Compare((DateTime)stellebeschreibung.VON_DATUM, dt1) >= 0
                                         select stellebeschreibung).ToList();

        return stelleBeschreibungAbDatum;
    }

}
```

Controller + ViewModel:

```
 private IStellenBeschrRepository _repository;

    public Default1Controller()
        : this(new Stellenbeschr_Repo())
    { 

    }

    public Default1Controller(IStellenBeschrRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    #endregion

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.ListAktuell());
    }

    public ActionResult Stellenliste()
    {
        var viewModels = new StellenlisteViewModel { StellenListe = _repository.ListAktuell() };
        return View(viewModels);
    }
     public class StellenlisteViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<STELLENBESCHREIBUNGEN> StellenListe { get; set; }

}
```

Viewpage extract:

```
 @foreach(var item in Model.StellenListe)
{
    <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.Display(item.STELLENBESCHREIBUNG);
    </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The Viewpage is currently displaying ";" for every item the LINQ expression has found

I just cant find a solution to get the list displayed in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely your view code.

Make sure your model is declared as:

```
@model StellenlisteViewModel
```

and not:

```
@model IEnumerable<StellenlisteViewModel>
```

**EDIT**

From the sounds of it you may be confusing a few things.

Your page will have a single view model. On this view model will be a list of `STELLENBESCHREIBUNGEN` which you are wanting to display.

To do this, first make sure your view page accepts a single view model:

```
@model StellenlisteViewModel
```

Secondly, you want to add a `ToList()` call in your repository:

```
    var stelleBeschreibungAbDatum = (from stellebeschreibung in db.STELLENBESCHREIBUNGEN
                                     where DateTime.Compare((DateTime)stellebeschreibung.VON_DATUM, dt1) >= 0
                                     select stellebeschreibung).ToList();
```

Thirdly, your view page will look something like this:

```
@model StellenlisteViewModel


foreach(var item in Model.StellenListe)
{
    // output each individual item to the page
    // here you can access the individual properties on your STELLENBESCHREIBUNGEN, e.g.:
    <span>@item.Description</span>
}
```

Sorry, I don't have access to MVC3 currently, so I can't check the syntax.

**EDIT#2**

You are using `Display` incorrectly. You may wish to check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.display.aspx) for it.

It is also like [`DisplayFor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: But I want it to be populated as an IEnumerable, so I can fill it in a table.

Comment: @user1249641 could you post your view page?

Comment: There is no ViewPage yet, because I can't populate the data in the View. I am not able to adress any of the properties in the model like Description; start date, end date; ref-number and so on.

Comment: but here it is anyways:
sorry ... the"@" prevent me from posting the viewpage somehow ... im not used to stackoverflow

Comment: `code`

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.LabelFor(item.PROPERTY);
    </td>
    </tr>
}
`code`

but i can't select ANY property. The only Item I can select is 'StellenListe'

Comment: @user1249641 I have updated my answer, you want to iterate over the `StellenListe` property on your model, and not the model itself.

Comment: doesnt work either. If I don't call `code`@model IEnumerable`code`, I cant use foreach. 

foreach(var item in Model.STELLENLISTE) doesnt work either. I dont have a property StellenListe available.

`code`@Item.ANYTHING `code`.. same

Comment: @user1249641 `StellenListe` is the property on your view model. Does your code match what you have originally posted in the question? Are there compilation errors? I noticed you wrote `Model.STELLENLISTE`. Is this exactly what you typed? C# is case-sensitive and you need to have correct casing (i.e. it should match what is defined in your view model class, hence: `Model.StellenListe`)

Comment: no, I just used it to highlight. I'm fully aware of CS
I rewrote some lines in the viewPage and now without IEnumerable it accepts foreach ... for whatever reason.

Now I am also able to select the item.Properties correctly, but I get the error: (sorry german)

 Typargumente der System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)-Methode können nicht per Rückschluss aus der Syntax abgeleitet werden. Geben Sie die Typargumente explizit an.

Comment: @user1249641 Also make sure you have the `@model StellenlisteViewModel` correct when attempting to write `foreach(var item in Model.StellenListe)`. The `@model` tag sets the type for the `Model` variable.

Comment: @user1249641 have you added the `ToList()` call in your repository? LINQ will defer execution, and without the `ToList()` call it is likely you no longer have access the context in the view. Actually, upon reading the error, it is likely you are using the `DisplayFor` extension with the wrong syntax. Could you edit your original question with the current code you are working with? It is difficult to simply guess the problem :)

Comment: @user1249641 I have made a minor update to my answer. Unfortunately it is past midnight where I am, so this will be my last edit. I also feel like we have exceeded the scope of the original question a little bit, so you may want to ask a different question now that you have your view model issue sorted.

Comment: Well ... for now he just doesnt accept the `DisplayFor(item.Property)`.
I think I can figure out why on my own, if somebody wants to jump in - feel free to ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your are returning a single item rather than a list of items. You either need to declare the view to take `marc_bew_online.ViewModels.StellenlisteViewModel` (rather than an IEnumerable) or return a list of the viewmodel items.